# Copy blob to asset in Azure media services using PHP SDK

Tags: php, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I'm using Azure PHP SDK for Azure Media services and having problem with uploading large files (< 64 mb). So i tried using Blob service to upload as a chunk and commit it as a single file. It also works fine, and now media services won't directly take blob as a input. So i need to convert it into an Asset.

I'm following the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj933290.aspx which has example using .NET, is there a PHP sdk library support available for copying blob to asset. If yes please let me know the class and its methods or link.

Please advice

Comment: Anybody tried this using Azure PHP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same solution.

@Jason Tang - MSFT mentioned `BlobRestProxy::copyBlob` commenting [his own answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28865807/1983572)

But I've tried to create an asset and copy to blob to it using this method I what I get was a destination container not found.

What I'm trying to do right now is use `Iblob::getBlob` to get blobs content and use `MediaServicesRestProxy::uploadAssetFile` passing the blob contente as third parameter.